# VueJS - create readonly copy of a ref object (Composition API)

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3, readonly, vue-composition-api

I am getting data from db by onMounted hook and showing object in a form. When user clicks to save, I just want to check if object data has changed or not.

```
onMounted(async () => {
  loadingBasic.value = true
  const doc = await getDocument('workspaces',props.uid) //doc is ref({}) also
  wspace.value = doc.value
  loadingBasic.value = false
})
```

I created a readonly object but when wspace object has changed, readonly object is changing, too. How can I create an unchanged initial copy of a ref object?

By the way, is there another easy way to check form changes?

Comment: Deep cloning in js: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/122102/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-deep-clone-an-object-in-javascript?answertab=scoredesc#tab-top

Comment: You need JSON.parse and stringfy you will change reference of your object for this reason and doesn't happen side effect;
https://jsfiddle.net/ayaz323/7mpjnagL/6/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are copying only the reference with `wspace.value = doc.value`
You can copy values with:

```
wspace.value = {...doc.value}
```

```js
let doc1 = {a: 1, b:2}
let doc2 = {a: 1, b:2}
let wspace1 = doc1
let wspace2 = {...doc2}

wspace1.a = 3
wspace2.a = 3

console.log('wspace1 :', wspace1)
console.log('doc1 :', doc1)
console.log('wspace2 :', wspace2)
console.log('doc2 :', doc2)
```

Answer (score 1):

Few suggestions **:**

- Instead of `shallow copy`, you have to do `deep copy` of an object to maintain the initial state. You can check the difference in both [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/184710/what-is-the-difference-between-a-deep-copy-and-a-shallow-copy).
- To create a deep copy of an object, You can try any of the following methods **:**

  - `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(object))`
  - By using [spread](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) operator `{...obj}` and assigning the result into a new variable.
- To quickly compare the changed and original object without any iteration. If the objects to be compared have properties in the same order, You can use [JSON.stringify()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify).

**Demo :**

```js
const doc = {
    value: {
    id: 1,
    name: 'alpha'
  }
};

// making a deep copy
const deepCopy = {...doc.value}

// As user did not make any changes in the form. Comparision should return true.
console.log(JSON.stringify(deepCopy) === JSON.stringify(doc.value)); // True

// User making some changes in the form.
deepCopy.id = 2;
deepCopy.name = 'beta';

// As user make changes in the form data. Comparision should return false.
console.log(JSON.stringify(deepCopy) === JSON.stringify(doc.value)); // False
```

Comment: Note the spread operator only performs a shallow clone. JSON.parse/stringify will perform a deep clone, but only of objects serializable into JSON.

Answer (score 0):

Deep copy  should be performed with: 
 StructuredClone
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/structuredClone 
const  Copiedbar = structuredClone(foo)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to import toRaw ?

```
import { toRaw } from 'vue';
wspace = toRaw(doc)
```